# Symfony API Platform. How properly insert complex data?

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I have entities Product and Host

Product

```
-------------------------------------------------
id   host_id           url               name
-------------------------------------------------
1      1    http://example.com/1/2/3   product_1
```

Host

```
----------
id   host   
----------
1    example.com
```

When I add a Product, I need to create a host (from url) if I don’t have one yet and substitute an id in host_id

For example i send Product data

```
{
    url: http://exmaple2.com/2/3/4
    name: super_product
}
```

Those. before creating a Product i need to create a host (example2.com). And then insert id to host_id in Product.

How and where should I create correctly Host?

In that case, do I need to create Product and Host in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `Site` while sending data:

```
{
    url: http://exmaple2.com/2/3/4,
    name: super_product,
    host: {"host": "example.com"}
}
```

Api-platform should create the host is the entites are correctly defined and the `host` property is writable.

---

Or, you can use a [Doctrine event listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) for that, it will be triggered automatically when a `Product` will be created.

Create a Subscriber class:

```
// src/EventListener/SearchIndexerSubscriber.php
namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

class ProductListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            Events::postPersist,
        );
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        if ($entity instanceof Product) {
            // Create site
            $site = new Site();
            // Set data you need
            $site->setUrl(…);
            // Create site
            $entity->setSite($site);

            $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();
            $entityManager->persist($product);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the different events on [Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events).

Tag the service with `doctrine.event_subscriber` tag:

```
    App\EventListener\ProductListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
```